# Automatically promoting input values for LLVM instructions

Tags: c++, llvm

When using the IR Builder obviously I can build IR that is invalid, e.g. by adding two values with incompatible type, like `i32` and `float`. Is there a facility that kind of promotes values (or better users) automatically according to the semantics of the instruction? Something like:

```
Value * CreateSafeFAdd (Value *LHS, Value *RHS, const Twine &Name="", MDNode *FPMathTag=0)
```

which would promote input values, e.g. in case they are integers. And it would promote to the higher floating-point precision, in case one of the input arguments' type is `float` and the other is `double`.

If not, I assume I will have to take of all type conversions in order to build valid IR.

Answer (score 1):

Type conversations must be handled by the one building the IR, but you could make your own CreateSafeFAdd function using `Value::getType()`